# Maven POM confusion

Tags: java, maven

I'm unable to run any command in Maven without receiving the following message:

The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory . Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

This happens even when attempting to run these commands, which are intended to CREATE a POM.

`mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app`

I'm following the steps here, http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/ and I started from the very beginning. I'm really not sure how to get past this if there's no way for me to set up a POM initially, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try to run the command on a single line

Comment: It works nicely on Ubuntu. So maybe in your case its a OS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are on Windows. There you must use the carret `^` instead of the backslash `\` to wrap a long command line

for Windows

```
mvn -B archetype:generate ^
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes ^
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app ^
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

for Linux

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "\" characters, and try again.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this into notepad and remove all `\` characters so that you get one long line. Then paste in cmd. Should work. And the message you are seeing usually means that you try to run `mvn` from a folder which does not contain `pom.xml`